# Self signed certificate jetty

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, jetty, cas

I'm using Jetty server to run CAS (http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.1.x/index.html).
  To enable ssl support I have generate a certifice with the follows commands:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out jetty.key
openssl req -new -x509 -key jetty.key -out jetty.crt
keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file jetty.crt -trustcacerts
openssl req -new -key jetty.key -out jetty.csr
openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore
```

Then, in `etc/jetty-ssl.xml` I set my .crt file.

However trying use CAS over a PHP app I'm barred by SSL issues.

As my cert is self signed, how can I add it as a secure certificate?

Thanks in advanced.

**Edit**

I run curl: `curl -v "https ://mydomain.org/myapp/myservice"`.

And the output was:

```
* About to connect() to mydomain.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying myip... connected
* Connected to mydomain.com (myip) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Certificate is signed by an untrusted issuer: 'CN=mycn,O=myo,L=myl,ST=myst,C=myc'
* NSS error -8172
* Closing connection #0
* Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I know this happens because certificate is self-signed, but I like to know if there a way to ignore it just in my dev environment.

**Edit 2**

The error `CURL error #35: Encountered end of file` makes any sense?

Comment: Could you provide examples/excerpts of the exact SSL issues you are seeing?

Comment: @Castaglia I put the output of curl. Thank for help.

Comment: For development purposes, you can tell `curl` to ignore the cert verification error using _e.g._: `curl -v -k https://example.com/myapp/myservice`.  After that, you will need to see how to add your self-signed cert to the NSS database that `curl` is using.

Comment: @Castaglia I'm using curl in order to debug, the goal is use the php client (that in fact use curl). `curl myurl --cacert mycacert.crt` works well.
I'll see how to add the self-signed cert to NSS database.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `CURL error #35: Encountered end of file` makes sense?